# Force setState before another function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, state

How can I force `setSearchedMovie` to be finished before `fetchSearchedMovie(searchedMovie)` function is called?

```
  const { updateMovies, searchedMovie, setSearchedMovie } = useContext(MoviesContext); 

  const fetchMoviesList = (event: any) => {
    const searchedMovieValue = event.target.value;
    setSearchedMovie(searchedMovieValue);

    if (searchedMovie) {
      fetchSearchedMovie(searchedMovie)
        .then((res) => updateMovies(res))
        .catch(() => updateMovies([]));
    } else {
      fetchMovies()
        .then((res) => updateMovies(res))
        .catch(() => updateMovies([]));
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `useEffect` hook:

```
const { updateMovies, searchedMovie, setSearchedMovie } = useContext(MoviesContext); 

const fetchMoviesList = (event: any) => {
    const searchedMovieValue = event.target.value;
    setSearchedMovie(searchedMovieValue);
}

useEffect(()=>{
    if (searchedMovie) {
      fetchSearchedMovie(searchedMovie)
        .then((res) => updateMovies(res))
        .catch(() => updateMovies([]));
    } else {
      fetchMovies()
        .then((res) => updateMovies(res))
        .catch(() => updateMovies([]));
    }
}, [searchedMovie, fetchSearchedMovie, fetchMovies, updateMovies]);
```

You can even integrate this hook into the `MoviesContextProvider` if you want this functionality to run every time searchedMovie is changed via `setSearchMovie` (I'm assuming you are using `useState` for these)

Comment: This works, thanks! I assumed I should use useEffect() though I didn't get at which part of the component to do it